# How to enable an eclipse MenuItem from Java Code if it is being disabled from Plugin.xml

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have created a MenuItem and made it disable in Plugin.xml.

```
<enableFor = false>
```

Now I want to enable the above MenuItem but only THROUGH JAVA or business logic.
How to do?

Comment: @Abishek - What is triggered when the user clicks on this menu item? A command or an action?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using objectContributions or actionSets, your IActionDelegate can set the menu item enablement in the `run(IAction)` or `selectionChanged(IAction, ISelection)` method.

If you are using commands and handlers (recommended), then you can write an enabledWhen core expression [1].  You can declaratively use any of the variables provided, and you can write a PropertyTester [2] to programmatically provide the enabled state.

[1] http://wiki.eclipse.org/Command_Core_Expressions 
[2] http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_Expression_Framework